# Unable to give condition to watcher for elasticsearch?

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch, scripting, mailing, elasticsearch-watcher

I installed watcher and giving the condition. While giving the condition its giving me error that...

`{"error":"WatcherException[failed to put watch [log_error_watch]]; nested:` `ScriptConditionValidationException[failed to compile script [return` `ctx.payload.hits.total > 5] with lang [groovy] of type [INLINE]]; nested:` `ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; ","status":500}`

What is dynamic scripting? Its giving me error that it is disabled. 
My condition to the watcher is as follows.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_watcher/watch/log_error_watch' -d '{
  "metadata" : { 
    "color" : "red"
  },
  "trigger" : { 
    "schedule" : {
      "interval" : "10s"
    }
  },
  "input" : { 
    "search" : {
      "request" : {
        "search_type" : "count",
        "indices" : "logs",
        "body" : {
          "query" : { "match" : { "status" : "error" } }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition" : { 
    "script" : "return ctx.payload.hits.total > 5"
  },
  "transform" : { 
    "search" : {
        "request" : {
          "indices" : "logs",
          "body" : {
            "query" : { "match" : { "status" : "error" } }
          }
        }
    }
  },
  "actions" : { 
    "my_webhook" : {
      "webhook" : {
        "method" : "GET",
        "host" : "mylisteninghost",
        "port" : 9200,
        "path" : "/{{watch_id}}",
        "body" : "Encountered {{ctx.payload.hits.total}} errors"
      }
    },
    "email_administrator" : {
      "email" : {
        "to" : "xxxxxx.xxx@gmail.com",
        "subject" : "Encountered {{ctx.payload.hits.total}} errors",
        "body" : "Too many error in the system, see attached data",
        "attach_data" : true,
        "priority" : "high"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 3):

@andrei is right about how to enable dynamic scripting in Elasticsearch, and I was about to paste the same link.

However, based on the condition you specified, it looks like you don't actually need to use scripting at all! Watcher has a `compare` condition, which looks like a perfect fit:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/condition.html#condition-compare

In your case, the condition would look like this:

```
    {
  ...

  "condition" : {
    "compare" : {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total" : { 
        "gte" : 5 
      }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I removed watcher history and installed again. im getting error like this again..
.
----------------------------------------------------->
{"error":"WatcherException[failed to put watch [error_status]]; nested: StrictDynamicMappingException[mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [_status] within [watch] is not allowed]; ","status":500}

Comment: It looks like you had a pre-release version of watcher installed. Please follow the instructions here to upgrade: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/release-notes.html#upgrade-instructions

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable dynamic scripting in Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/condition.html#condition-script

> A watch condition that evaluates a script. The default scripting language is groovy. You can use any of the scripting languages supported by Elasticsearch as long as the language supports evaluating expressions to Boolean values. Note that the mustache and expression languages are too limited to be used by this condition. For more information, see Scripting in the Elasticsearch Reference.
>
> Important
>
> You must explicitly enable dynamic scripts in elasticsearch.yml to use inline or indexed scripts.

And actually enabling dynamic scripting: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting